# Issue with mysql_connect and openssl_decrypt

Tags: php, mysql, php-openssl

I have an older app that is using this to connect to the database:

```
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password,false, MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
```

I recently introduced an encryption function that uses:

```
openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
```

After the openssl_decrypt is called the mysql_connect fails due to "mysql_query(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away"

I will be moving this to pdo (Yes I know you should not be using mysql_connect) soon but need to get this working now. Any insights as to how to work around this issue would be helpful.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code. The error is clearly in a MySQL query you are making. We also don't know the order of the call to `openssl_decrypt()` function and the `mysql_connect()` function. Also, why are you using the decryption function anyway? SSL encryption is handled within the connection.

Comment: 1) The decryption is for something other than the connection, it impacts the connection.  2) If I remove the encryption call which is unrelated to the SQL or move it to after the SQL the SQL runs fine. For some reason using openssl_decrypt() breaks the MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL constant which is odd but it is happening.

Comment: `or move it to after the SQL the SQL runs fine`...so why not do that?

Comment: Here is the flow: 1) SQL is called to pull in parameters. 2) A class is called and initialized also making a SQL call. 3) A function in that class runs and pulls in api data. A part of this function decrypts a value. 4) That data is looped and inserted into a table if new the error happens on insert. If I print out the query and run that query it works fine. If I take the data kill the call and loop through it and insert it works fine. If I go to a separate test script and encrypt a random string then do a simple select it fails. Same error with the SSL to the database. So can't move it.

Comment: Normally you would only need one connection throughout the lifetime of the application, so just make the connection first and keep the object in memory throughout the lifetime of the application. Or are you saying that subsequent DB calls still fail even if you run mysql_connect before the  openssl_decrypt call? It wasn't quite clear, from the description.

Comment: Yes subsequent DB calls still fail even if you run mysql_connect before the openssl_decrypt call.

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong with such an old API. We can't even test it properly ourselves as most of us don't even have an environment set up for such an old PHP version. There could be a bug in PHP, or there could be a bug in your code. Is there any chance you can convert your app to PDO?

Comment: Or, if you don't have time to convert everything to PDO right now, maybe just start with the SQL calls which occur after you've run openssl_decrypt. From your description, it might only be one insert statement?

Comment: I may go that route. Right now I'm looking into an alternative to openSSL